# Running debug node_module on Openshift

Tags: node.js, express, openshift

I recently started using Openshift and it's been great so far. My current problem lies on the fact that my debug logs are not showing in Openshift's logs. I used to run the app locally with `DEBUG=*,-express:* node ./bin/www` and it showed everything I needed. So far I haven't figured how to translate this into the `package.json` file so that it works as intended.

```
package.json
{
  "name": "APP",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "DEBUG=*,-express:* node ./bin/www"
  },
  "main": "./bin/www",
  "dependencies": { ... }
```

It seems to me that it is running the `node` command with the `main` data, instead of my much preferred script. I believe that the debug module is a great alternative to spamming `console.log()` on my code.

On the OpenShift log files it shows the following when starting the app. It is my understanding I am looking to find the --exec and change.

```
DEBUG: Running node-supervisor with
DEBUG:   program './bin/www'
DEBUG:   --watch '/var/lib/openshift/<app_ID>/app-root/data/.nodewatch'
DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js|coffee'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node ./bin/www'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-getting-started.html)
and search for "markers", you'll find this:

> use_npm:
>
> Initialize your application or service using *npm start*
>   instead of **supervisor servername.js** (where servername.js is based
>   on the value of your package.json’s **main** attribute).

I still think that it is better for you to use supervisor. But you can modify the value of debug within the code by having

```
process.env.DEBUG='*,-express:*';
```

before the first use of require("debug"), at least as a temporary solution.

HTH